# Usage of "least of all"

Tags: idiom-meaning

Please help me to understand the meaning of "least of all" and how to use it correctly in a sentence.

Is it correct if I use it like this?

> Least of all are politicians.

Comment: "Least of all are politicians" seems like a possible sentence to me. To know if it's correct, though, you'd need to tell us what you want to express with this sentence. What do you think it means?

Answer (score 1):

Let's get a few things straight about this expression:

First, you seldom see the copula used because it is not really a stand-alone expression:

> . . . least of all <strike>are</strike> politicians.

In keeping with that, you seldom see it used except as a subordinate clause:

> Tom said he would never willingly go to a speech by government workers, least of all politicians.

What the construction normally does is set aside a subset of a group for special emphasis. The usual form is something like

`[SUBJECT] [CONDITION] [MAIN GROUP]  -> least of all [SUB GROUP]`

In other words, we say that something regarding a group (usually one we dislike) is especially true of a subset of that group.

Another way to phrase the above would be:

> Tom said he would not willingly go to a speech by government workers, and that is especially true of politicians.

or

> Tom said he would not willingly go to a speech by government workers, and that goes double for politicians.

Anywhere you could say "especially not" you could substitute "least of all." Similarly, anywhere you could say "especially" you could substitute "most of all."

Comment: But "least of all" may also be used on its own, as a parallel to "greatest of all". In the sentence "least of all are politicians" it seems like it might possibly be being used in this sense. It's somewhat archaic but still used at times, I think, especially in religious contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context in which you would like to use "Least of all are politicians".

But here's one, in which the phrase or sentence will make sense:

Generally, religious leaders and philanthropists are selfless individuals. Least of all, are politicians.